# using tidymodels extraction functions with dplyr and error handling

Tags: r

leveraging tidymodels workflow sets to create and run many models at once. subsequently, using `extract_fit_parsnip()` to return the model object and `tidy()` to return a clean dataframe that contains model outputs (i.e. coef label, coefs, p-values).  However, not all models contain parameter estimates. For example:

```
all_models_workflow_final_variable_coef = all_models %>%
  extract_workflow(id = "logistic_recipe_logistic_model") %>%
  finalize_workflow(all_models_workflow_sets_variable_importance) %>%
  last_fit(dat_split) %>%
  extract_fit_parsnip() %>% 
  tidy()
```

...returns a clean tibble with "term, "estimate", "std.error," "statistic,"p.value" headers and respective values. But the following:

```
all_models_workflow_final_variable_coef = all_models %>%
  extract_workflow(id = "naive_bayes_recipe_naive_bayes_model") %>%
  finalize_workflow(all_models_workflow_sets_variable_importance) %>%
  last_fit(dat_split) %>%
  extract_fit_parsnip() %>% 
  tidy()
```

...returns the error `Error: No tidy method for objects of class naive_bayes`.  which makes sense for the given model.

Trying to find a way to extract and tidy when model fit metrics are relevant, otherwise continue.  I've tried using tryCatch(), and purrrs `safely()` and `possibly()` error handling functions.  For example:

```
all_models_workflow_final_variable_coef = all_models %>%
  extract_workflow(id = "naive_bayes_recipe_naive_bayes_model") %>%
  finalize_workflow(all_models_workflow_sets_variable_importance) %>%
  last_fit(dat_split) %>%
  extract_fit_parsnip() %>% 
  safely(tidy)
```

...returns

```
Error in `as_mapper()`:
! Can't convert `.f`, a <_naive_bayes/model_fit> object, to a function.
```

**Update**

Found a workaround. Ideally, the solution would be more dynamic, vice having to create a logical around the extraction object, then run `tidy()`.

```
all_models_workflow_final_variable_coef = all_models %>%
  extract_workflow(id = "naive_bayes_recipe_naive_bayes_model") %>%
  finalize_workflow(all_models_workflow_sets_variable_importance) %>%
  last_fit(dat_split) %>%
  extract_fit_parsnip()
```

Create logical boolean

```
estimate_class_check = !is(all_models_workflow_final_variable_coef, "_naive_bayes")
```

Run `tidy()`with a conditional against the logical check

```
  all_models_workflow_final_variable_importance_coef = 
    if(isTRUE(estimate_class_check)) {
      all_models_workflow_final_variable_coef %>%
        tidy() %>%
        mutate(model_group = workflow_id)
    }
```

Comment: could you just write `tidy.naive_bayes <- function(...){NULL}`, which should just return `NULL` when `tidy()` is called on an object of class `naive_bayes`?  I can't test without a reproducible example.

Comment: thanks.  tried applying the `function(...){NULL}` approach using tidy options (`safely()`, `possibly()`) and the traditional `tryCatch()`.  Wasn't able to get either to work.  But the idea helped with finding the above workaround. Certainly open for any improvements.

Comment: Why not just write `tidy` methods for the classes that don't have one already?